# Is there a way to convert a varchar to DATETIME in SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example this is the varchar --> `'24/05/2012 09:56:06'`
and I want to convert it to a DATETIME

Comment: Have you even checked the online documents for `CONVERT`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this :

```
convert(datetime,'24/05/2012 09:56:06',103)
```

[image]

also  , refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I think we have haters here, just joking :p

Comment: I mean someone voted  the solution down, and someone voted to close my question.

Answer (score 2):

See [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The style `dd/mm/yyyy` is 103:

```
select convert(datetime, '24/05/2012 09:56:06', 103);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> **select convert(datetime,'24/05/2012 09:56:06',120)**

See this link: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

It shows you more date formats of sql. Use it whatever u need.

Comment: The OP's example format is clearly `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss`, yet you suggest style 120, which has the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`???

Comment: yea thanq for ur comment i suggest it for the conversion and i sent the link for various formats whatever they like.

Comment: Exactly SaranyaJothiprakasam, @Dems is this question offending you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this more accurate to cater your need.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ydm
DECLARE @D DATETIME
SELECT @D = CAST('24/05/2012 09:56:06' AS DATETIME)

SELECT @D AS MYDATETIME
```

Comment: Can you give me a example of that just to enhance my knowledge base? Please do not mind it.

Comment: my mistake , i meant some other sample  like yyyy-mm-dd  which once faile in set languge british... or something

Comment: It never happened to me but I take your point. Thanx anyways.

Comment: here is the sample ( ive found it ) `set language british; select CAST('2012-03-31' AS DATETIME)`

Comment: Check the Books Online page for CAST and CONVERT.  You'll see a whole host of different date formats.  Only by using CONVERT can you specify a format.  As RoyiNamir suggests, using CAST assumes a format based on your language settings, etc.