# Converting varchar datatype to datetime datatype using SQL 2012 management studio

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a column which has `ddmmmyyyy:hh:mm:ss.nnnnnn` it is stored as `varchar(25)`. I need to save it as datetime in the same column. I have tried using

```
update tablename
set columnname = (SUBSTRING(columnname,1,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(columnname,3,3) + '-' + 
SUBSTRING(columnname,6,4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(columnname,11,8));
```

and then

```
alter table tablename    
alter columnname datetime;
```

but later it shows up the error

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

How do I change it any other opinion or any modification for the above query. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**As per your given string format, you should use `datetime2` data type**

Your string format is almost correct, only 1 colon is extra after Year.

If you fix that thing, you can directly cast the `varchar` field into `datetime2`. For example first you can replace the extra colon with space by running following query,

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET targetColumn = STUFF ( targetColumn , 10, 1, ' ')
-- ddmmmyyyy:hh:mm:ss.nnnnnn
--           \
--           this colon is extra which is at 10th position
```

After this you can directly `ALTER` your table and change the data type to `datetime2`.

**Important: data in all the lines must contain valid date**

Here is a test which shows how you can convert

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(testCol varchar(25));

INSERT INTO testTable(testCol)
    VALUES('03Jan2014 18:33:39.999999');

ALTER TABLE testTable ALTER COLUMN testCol datetime2;

SELECT  *
FROM    testTable

DROP TABLE testTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

It has already been answered here: [Is there a way to convert a varchar to DATETIME in SQL SERVER 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735447/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-varchar-to-datetime-in-sql-server-2008)

He uses: `convert(datetime,'24/05/2012 09:56:06',103)`

Although you might have to do some `substring`s to adapt to a format covered by `convert`: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Yes I did read it but I have more than 10,000 rows in one column and the date and timestamp are different. So that didn't work for me. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column

```
alter table t
add n datetime
```

Update the new column

```
update t
set n = datetimefromparts(
            cast(substring(o,6,4) as int),
            case substring(o,3,3)
                 when 'jan' then 1
                 ...
                 when 'dec' then 12
            end,
            cast(substring(o,1,2) as int),
            cast(substring(o,11,2) as int),
            cast(substring(o,14,2) as int),
            cast(substring(o,17,2) as int),
            cast(substring(o,20,6) as int)
        )
```

If you need to drop the old column

```
alter table t
drop column o
```

Comment: I tried to use what query you gave it shows up this error:                     Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The datetimefromparts function requires 7 argument(s).